# Is there some recommended way to create an id for a ParseObject for use in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a hash code using the Parse object id, but obviously this has some small potential to blow up.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<MyParseObject> mObjects;

    ...

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mObjects.get(position).getObjectId().hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you planning on utilizing the getItemId call? I would honestly look into an interface with a specific function to get the Parse ID if that is what you are really looking for. The hashCode collisions should be few and far between theoretically, but you are correct it could create issues.

Comment: I've done it before, but my main recommendation is that you create a local POJO and map parse data objects from it. Might seem redundant but thank me later. Just a good practice in general since middleware changes

Comment: Every ParseObject has a creation date associated with it. Create an item id from that using : long itemId = parseObject.getCreatedAt().getTime() + parseObject.getObjectId().hashCode();

Comment: Parse shut down. Use something else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not specific to Parse, but you could create stable ids easily from the object id:

```
public class StableNumericalIdProvider {
    private int idProvider;
    private final Map<String, Integer> numericalIds = new HashMap<>();

    public int id(String stringId) {
        Integer numericalId = numericalIds.get(stringId);
        if (numericalId == null) {
            numericalId = idProvider++;
            numericalIds.put(stringId, numericalId);
        }
        return numericalId;
    }
}

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<MyParseObject> mObjects;

    private StableNumericalIdProvider idProvider;

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return idProvider.id(mObjects.get(position).getObjectId());
    }
}
```

(on a side note, do you need to implement `getItemId`? If your dataset is not changing, you don't have to)

Comment: I'm using a SwipeRefreshLayout, so implementing it prevents flickering

Answer (score -3):

Why do you need to provide ids?

Try using
`setHasStableIds(true)` on the recyclerview ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#hasStableIds())) and change your `getItemId` method to return the position only:

```
public int getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```